# Can I set the default format for a double when using Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, .net, console.writeline

Are there any options for setting the default format when writing a `double` value to the console?

I have many `double` values to output to the console, and I need set the format to two decimal places on all of them, like `Math.Round(number, 2)`.

Can I set this for all of them?

Right now I'm using:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} x {2}",
                  Math.Round(a, 2), Math.Round(b, 2), Math.Round(c, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

`Console.Writeline` is just a function that outputs a string to the console. You can't change the "default" format for strings, so the basic answer to your question is **NO**.

However, your code can be simplified. By specifying a format string, you can avoid the use of `Math.Round`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D2} x {1:D2} x {2:D2}", a, b, c);
```

"D2" is a decimal number out to 2 decimal places. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for other common formatting strings. Note that this works because `Console.Writeline` invokes `String.Format` under the hood.

As to *why* you can't do this; `String.Format` takes each argument and calls `ToString` on it. It then applies the formatting string (if any). You can't override `ToString` for a `double` so there is no way to change the "default".

Comment: I know that, but it not clean code. When I find that I need at all to show 3 decimal numbers so I have a problem, so I have at least constat and the use of Math.Round

Comment: @Peter How is that not clean? You can't force `double.ToString` to behave differently. I don't know what you expect here. I did add an explanation of this to my answer; hopefully its useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, if you find that you do have to use `Math.Round` (or perform some other operation on the numbers) is to write your own method for rounding the numbers.

This will round each number you pass in, then create a single string out of the numbers (placing an "x" between each one, similar to your output):

```
private static void WriteNumbers(IEnumerable<double> numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" x ", numbers.Select(n => Math.Round(n, 2))));
}
```

And then just pass it an array of doubles to operate on:

```
WriteNumbers(new[] {2.2344, 3.323, 5.23432});
```

Output:

> 2.23 x 3.32 x 5.23

Comment: Thats possible, but it not be used if I have Console.WWriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", doubleVariable, stringVarible, doubleVariable2)